# Не могу настроить spring boot security, подскажите как лучше?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-security

пишу проект блогового движка на spring boot. Хочу настроить секьюрити с использованием jwt.
Если пользователь авторизован, идентификатор его сессии должен запоминаться в Map со значением, равным ID пользователя, которому принадлежит данная сессия. подскажите лучшие варианты плиз. Также не понятен еще один момент, а именно - обязательно ли создавать имплементацию UserDetails, чтобы сохранять залогининых пользавателей, или же можно как то по другому настроить User-a?

Comment: Да, и еще интересно как получить  id сессии, я так  понимаю она нужна для сохранения в Мапе?

Comment: При JWT сессия не нужна от слова совсем. Вы смешиваете два подхода к построению приложений: REST API и приложения где и бэк и фронт в одном и там участвует сессия (зачастую). В REST-е (Что вы и пытаетесь сделать) при каждом запросе `Security` авторизовывает пользователя на основании JWT токена. Всех авторизованных юзверей Секюрити хранит у себя на каждый запрос. То бишь как только запрос выполнился - все данные уничтожаются ибо при новом запросе они будут новые.

Comment: Вот это требования по проекту -  "Если пользователь авторизован, идентификатор его сессии должен запоминаться в Map со значением, равным ID пользователя, которому принадлежит данная сессия".  Это значит jwt не для меня??

Comment: верно, не для вас. Когда используется сессия никакие другие токены не нужны ибо "токеном" является значение куки `JSESSIONID` в куках клиента.

Comment: можете кинуть годноту по моей теме? а то не могу ничего найти похожего, чтобы с сохранением JSESSIONID. заранее благодарю

Comment: С сохранением где? это и так сохраняется в контейнере сервлетов (tomcat e.t.c) и вы можете получить сессию из объекта класса `HttpServletRequest`. Просто проверяйте не новая ли сессия и есть ли там нужный параметр, который отвечает за то что юзверь авторизован.

Comment: Да, еще б понять как это реализовать))

Comment: я уже могу заходить во логину и паролю, но как реализовывать методы, в которых требуется авторизация? я гоняю через Постман, что там нужно указывать? логин  и пароль в теле запроса?

Comment: логин и пароль залогинненного пользака?

Comment: Если Вы храните данные об авторизации в сессии, то Вы шлете логин и пароль на определенный `url` для авторизации. Проверяете там данные и если все хорошо, то записываете в сессию информацию о том что юзер авторизован. Далее в фильтрах Секюрити достаете сессию и проверяете эти самые параметры.

Comment: А как это будет выглядеть в постмане? Например запрос о получении всех постов должен быть авторизован, как будет проходить вся процедура? Просто я делал на jwt, в том случае подставлял готовый токен в header и далее проверял, как работает запрос

Comment: Вам нужно будет передавать куку `JSESSIONID=value`.